# Laravel cache key prefix is prepended with database prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

The cache prefix setting has the default value:

```
'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_cache')
```

But when I cache some data (using Redis), the cache key has an unexpected format:

```
app_database_app_cache:some-data
```

The cache key is prefixed with the database prefix. I expected the cache key to just be:

```
app_cache:some-data
```

Is this the correct behavior, and is it possible to change it somewhere?

Comment: what is `env('CACHE_PREFIX')`

Comment: It's not set, so it sets the fallback value, which is the default one as seen above.

Comment: the default one is `laravel_cache`, so i think your `env('CACHE_PREFIX')` is `app_database_app_cache`

Comment: My APP_NAME env var is set to 'app'.

Comment: Out of interest, is you set `env('CACHE_PREFIX')`, does it effect any new keys?

Comment: @TsaiKoga thank you! settings CACHE_PREFIX fixed my problem

Answer (score 6):

For those who still lost, Redis key is the combination of two variables in Laravel.

1. REDIS_PREFIX - `config/database.php`

```
'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
```

2. CACHE_PREFIX - `config/cache.php`

```
'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_cache'),
```

If you see an unexpected prefix or suffix in your key, you'd better look at those two.

Answer (score 5):

I somehow didn't notice the `REDIS_PREFIX` env var which prepends a prefix. The file caching of config.php also made it harder to debug.